# Coordinates of char in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, coordinates

I have a problem. I have UILabel(150*50px), where is center-aligned text. I wanna coordinates of char in word. For example I have word "format" and I wanna coordinates of char "r". I know that r is on second position. It is possible get coordinates? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the low-level framework CoreText to calculate the font metrics of the font/size/stye you are using, allowing for letter kerning, etc. I haven't done this sort of calculation in iOS, but I have on other platforms. It's pretty complex, fussy code to write.

Comment: It is only one solution? Is there any way to get width of each letter?

Comment: Yes. Again, using CoreText. However, that won't give you accurate positioning because in many fonts letter pairs are "kerned" (The spacing is adjusted based on neighboring letters.)